# Imputation error: Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : invalid first argument

Tags: r, random-forest, imputation

I am trying to run the following code to impute data:

```
df_imp <- missForest(df)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid first argument
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you edit the question with a sample of what `df` is? You can get it with `dput(df)`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell what the issue is without seeing a sample or summary of your data. It could be caused by one of your columns being an unexpected data type - I believe missForest expects all numerical columns.

Another potential issue is the format of your `df` - is it a data.frame, matrix, tibble? Does this help:

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df_imp <- missForest(df)
```